# MVC 4 Add scaffolding view from controller throws error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I get an error when I attempt to add a view from a controller method using a scaffolding template. It doesn't really matter which template I choose, I get an error. I am using VS2012 Update 2.

The controller method and model are:

```
  public ActionResult EditInventoryItem(int id)
  {
     InventoryRepository repo = new InventoryRepository();
     Inventory inventoryItem = repo.GetSingle(id);
     return View(inventoryItem);
  }

    public class Inventory
   {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Number { get; set; }
      public string Description { get; set; }
      public string Category { get; set; }
      public string Group { get; set; }
      public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
      public string ManufacturerModelNumber { get; set; }
   }
```

I do not have a clue what is wrong. Yes, I have references to the assemblies mentioned in the error messages. The assemblies are System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, System.core, System.Data.Entity and System.Data.Linq. I am placing only one of the four messages - too long.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.O\Common7JDE\IteniTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC 4\CodeTemplates\AddView\CSHTML\Details.tt(-1,-1): error: The host threw an exception while trying to resolve the assembly reference System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations. The transformation will not be run. The following Exception was thrown: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembiy._nLoad(AssembtyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forintrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint. StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forintrospection. Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) at System,Reflection.RuntimeAssemblyjnternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forlntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssemblyinternalLoad(String assemblyString. Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivf-lostBinder, Boolean forintrospection) at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString. Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forintrospection) at System.Reflection.Assembly.t.oad(String assemblyString) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.Userlnterface.MvcTextTemplateHost.ResolveAssemb)yReference(String assemblyReference) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Engine.ResolveAssemblyReferences(ITextTemplatingEngineHost host, TemplateProcessingSession session)

**Update**: I cannot post images here, so link to properties below. Changing Copy Local did not alter behavior.

[DataAnnotations properties](http://i39.tinypic.com/rfgl.png)

Comment: I have seen comments on more than one site that Code Digger 0.95 was the culprit here.  If the answer provided by sophokless addressed this problem, please Accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem and it was related to the Microsoft Code Digger extension 0.95. Disabling the extension allowed the scaffolding process to work sucessfully without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to run it to actually see what is going on, plus I couldn't tell if you were listing your assemblies or the error code. But Here is what I think may be wrong. You're welcome to try it and see.

```
    public class InveentoryController : Controller
    {
       InventoryRepository repo = new InventoryRepository(); 

        public ActionResult EditInventoryItem(int id = 0)   
        {         
           Inventory inventoryItem = repo.inventoryItem.Find(id);
               if (inventoryItem == null)
           {
               return HttpNotFound();
           }
           return View(inventoryItem);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The error message above comes from a modal window after hitting the Add button in Add View. When I tried it this morning, I got a different error: "c:\temp\3fyklisp.0.cs(5,33): error CS0234: Compiling transformation: The type or namespace 'DataAnnotations' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ComponentModel' (are you missing an assembly reference)?" This error is repeated for 'Linq' in 'System.Data'

Comment: Go to references, and right click on System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations. Go to properties and take a screenshot and edit your question. The Copy Local should be set to False but sometimes changing it to true helps. It did for me when I had a CS0234 error on System.Web.